# Highlighting issue with InDesign pdf

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, pdf

When highlighting text in a PDF exported from InDesign, the highlight doesn't select the text in the right order. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You seem to be using the PDF reader built into Firefox.  Try using Adobe Acrobat Reader instead.

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends on how your INDD document is set up and there will be limitations here, but try checking the 'Create tagged PDF' option when exporting from InDesign.

- https://indesignsecrets.com/reasons-create-tagged-pdf.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your document was built using multiple text frames. If not then I would need to see the actual pdf to figure out your problem. Acrobat orders your text frames from the bottom layer to the top. To fix this document you will need to select the text frame in InDesign that should come first and bring it to the front. Then select the next frame and bring it to the front. Go through the whole document until everything is ordered properly. You can check your work in your layers pallet. Export a pdf. Now your text should select in the correct order in acrobat.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate what I am talking about.

[image: Text frames in InDesign Document]

[image: Text frames in Layers Pallet]